# before Insert the data to Db, Check whether all values are Exist or not in android?

Tags: android

before Insert the data to Db, Check whether all values are Exist or not..if its exist means no need to insert ...if not exist means insert the values in db.....

```
        sql_db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sql_db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor = sql_db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {  res_namestr[i] , res_eventidstr[i] , get_res_starttime[i], get_res_endtime[i], get_res_location[i] });

        int noOfRecords= cursor.getCount();
        Log.d("No-of-Records :",""+noOfRecords);

        if (noOfRecords> 0)
        {
//          Toast.makeText(context, "Table Already Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //  record not exist
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBHelper.E_NAME, res_namestr[i]);
            values.put(DBHelper.E_EVENT_ID, res_eventidstr[j]);
            values.put(DBHelper.E_STARTTIME, get_res_starttime[int_date]);
            values.put(DBHelper.E_ENDTIME, get_res_endtime[int_time]);
            values.put(DBHelper.E_LOCATION, get_res_location[int_loc]);

            sql_db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE, null, values);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: didn't get the requirement.. can you elaborate more? you want to check which values?

Comment: before inserting i want to check the values are already available in table if its not there means need to insert ....this is my values----cursor = sql_db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {  res_namestr[i] , res_eventidstr[i] , get_res_starttime[i], get_res_endtime[i], get_res_location[i] });

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: not inserting the new values

Comment: this is my query.....String query = "SELECT * FROM " + helper.TABLE +" where id =?;"; but the app is crashing ...Exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 5 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [insertWithOnConflict()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) method. If record does not exist, it will insert he record and return the id of that and if exist, it will return the id of existing record.